# Conditional Transpose in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I wanna transpose columns in conditions like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Product" : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
              "Question" : ["What", "When", "Where", "What", "When", "Where", "What", "When", "Where"],
              "Answer" : ["Car", "Friday", "German", "Bike", "Wednesday", "France", "Train", "Sunday", "America"]})
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone suggest an effective solution for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot('Product', 'Question', 'Answer') \
        .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(out)

# Output
  Product   What       When    Where
0       A    Car     Friday   German
1       B   Bike  Wednesday   France
2       C  Train     Sunday  America
```

Check [How can I pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)